# how to substitute a variable by a number in wolframalpha

Tags: mathematica, wolfram-alpha

Peace be upon you,

How can I compute
\begin{align*}
sin'(0)
\end{align*}
in Wolframalpha? like what in Maple, I try

```
subs(diff(sin(x),x),x=0)
```

But it doesn't work. I searched the web for "substitution in wolframalpha", but no helpful answer I got.

Comment: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1926870

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following all work:

> ReplaceAll[Diff[Sin[x], x] , {x -> 0}]
>
> D[Sin[x], x] /. {x -> 0}
>
> Diff[Sin[x], x] where x = 0
>
> Sin'(0)